# Filtering Images of Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I am trying to filter the photos as well as some other variables within my array on my website. I have the function below, but my photos are still not displaying. Any advice on what to do? I am fairly new to Javascript!

For some more background information, I am trying to display certain images of archived magazine covers. These covers will displayed through a filter chosen by the user. (i.e. specific year, brand, cover from the magazine). This is a project for my university class. You can copy the API link to inspect what my array looks like and the properties within it!

Any help would be so so gratefully recieved!

HTML:

```
<div class="data_display">

  <ul id="data_brand">

  </ul>

  <ul id="data_datePublished">

  </ul>

  <ul id="data_printCovers">

  </ul>

  <ul id="data_imgs">

  </ul>

  <!-- <img id="data_img" src="" alt=""> -->

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.data_display {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row-start: 12;
    /* align-content: space-between; */
    width: 70vw;
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
   }
  
   li {
     margin-top: 2vh;
     margin-bottom: 2vh;
   }
  
  img {
     margin-left: 2vh;
     height: auto;
  
   }
```

Javascript:

```
console.log("hello!");
const ul1 = document.getElementById('data_brand');
const ul2 = document.getElementById('data_datePublished');
const ul3 = document.getElementById('data_printCovers');
const ul4 = document.getElementById('data_imgs');

async function getPeople() { 
  let response = await fetch('https://api.airtable.com/v0/appi4i01ehJf6jzVP/Table%201?api_key=keyOInlFujAUpPC0f'); 
  let data = response.json(); 
  return data; 
}

getPeople().then(data => {
  console.log(data.records);
  makeList(data.records)
});

function makeList(records) {
  for(let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

    let brand = records[i].fields.Brand;
    let dataDatePublished = records[i].fields.DatePublished;
    let dataPrintCovers = records[i].fields.PrintCovers;
    let dataLinks = records[i].fields.Attachments[i].thumbnails.full.url;

    let listItem1 = document.createElement('li');
    let listItem2 = document.createElement('li');
    let listItem3 = document.createElement('li');
    let listItem4 = document.createElement('li');

    let imgZ = document.createElement('img');

    listItem1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    listItem2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataBrand));
    listItem3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataDatePublished));
    listItem4.appendChild(imgZ);

    imgZ.src = dataLinks;

    imgZ.style.width = 20 + "px";
    

  //   listItem4.src = dataLinks;

    // ul4.src = "https://" + dataLinks;

    ul1.appendChild(listItem1);
    ul2.appendChild(listItem2);
    ul3.appendChild(listItem3);
    ul4.appendChild(listItem4);
  }
}
```

Comment: your variables `name` and `dataBrand` do not exist in your snippet, also, you're always referring to the array's second item `records[1]` in your loop. Please check this slightly modified fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rsza10y6/

Comment: in javascript, `img.src` is not a valid command, use `img.setAttribute("src", your_url)` instead

Comment: @balexandre img.src is perfectly valid.

Comment: @GrafiCode I checked out the fiddle and copied the corrected code, would you have any idea as to why it is still not showing up?? doesn't seem to make sense to me especially if it is displayed in the fiddle...

Comment: here's a start @pompom https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/eYyQjaW?editors=1011

Comment: @balexandre  i figured it out, thank you so so soooo much i was really so stuck!!

Answer (score 0):

```
let brand = records[1].fields.Brand;
let dataDatePublished = records[1].fields.DatePublished;
let dataPrintCovers = records[1].fields.PrintCovers;
let dataLinks = records[1].fields.Attachments[0].thumbnails.full.url;
```

check this line of code, you are using `1`, instead of `i`
replace it and run it again

Comment: just changed it, still nothing ,:/